# Delete rows in R data.frame based on duplicate values in one column only

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I would like to know how can I delete duplicate row entries based on the identifier number in the first column of the data frame. Most functions like `duplicated()` and `unique()` check every single value in a row in order to identify duplicate rows. On the other hand, I'm interested in identifying duplicates on the basis of a single column only.

Here's an example:

```
ID  Test   Date Taken
1   POS    1/1/15
1   POS    2/8/14
2   NEG    7/9/13
2   NEG    4/10/12
2   NEG    2/5/08
```

and the desired result:

```
ID  Test   Date Taken
1   POS    1/1/15
2   NEG    7/9/13
```

Comment: `df[!duplicated(df$ID),]`

Comment: `library(dplyr)` and then
`df %>% distinct(df$ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually want to use a `filter()` operation for this in combination with `arrange()`

For example:

```
df %>%
arrange(desc(`Date Taken`)) %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
filter(row_number(`Date Taken`) == 1)
```

would get you the most recent observation for each ID.

You could also use a `summarise()`:

```
df %>%
arrange(desc(`Date Taken`)) %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
summarise(ID = first(ID))
```

If you didn't care about `Date Taken` making it into the result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
df[!duplicated(df$ID),]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unique`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df1), by = "ID")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the duplicated function.
If df is your dataframe :

```
df[duplicated(df$ID), ]
```

will returns you (duplicate is based on the ID here)

```
ID  Test   Date Taken
1   POS    1/1/15
2   NEG    7/9/13
```

Comment: Glad this helps ! Good luck and don't forget to accept the answer for further developers to be helped ;)